# Transparent background hide volume emision (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, volumetrics

Why transparent background option hide volume emission?
I use Cycles render.

Blendfiles:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33111
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33112

[image]

Comment: I noticed this myself a while ago, but didn't really realize what was going on at the time. It's possible to work around it using the emit pass in the compositor, but now that I think about it I'm rather convinced that it's a bug (especially as it works in viewport render). I've reported it [here](https://developer.blender.org/T42755).